# HTTP POST response failure angular 16

Tags: angular, httpclient, http-error

I'm bothered with an http failure response "Unknown error" and I didn't found where is the problem.
With PDO when I send my object to Mysql server login with messageText "string"  all is good and connected to Mysql, but when I add a query POST to table there is this error:

```
{"headers": {"normalizedNames": {},"lazyUpdate": null,"headers": {}},"status": 0,"statusText": "Unknown     Error","url": "https://www.boulangerieqc.com/assets/crudmysql/insert_message.php","ok": false,"name":     "HttpErrorResponse","message": "Http failure response for     https://www.boulangerieqc.com/assets/crudmysql/insert_message.php: 0 Unknown Error","error":     {"isTrusted": true}}
```

my .ts to catch my messageText is:

```
let connectionMysqlObjMessage={messageText:this.newMessage.value.messageText,db_host:this.extract.boulanger.db_host,db_username:this.extract.boulanger.db_username,db_name:this.extract.boulanger.db_name,db_password:this.extract.boulanger.db_password,}this.api.createMessageMysql(connectionMysqlObjMessage).subscribe((res)=>{console.log('avant api='+res)
```

my api:

```
createMessageMysql(MessageObj: Object) {return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'insert_message.php',MessageObj, {responseType: 'json'})}
```

If you have some ideas I will be happy to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems It's a CORS issue. Try to disable (or configure) it on server side. This should solved your issue

Answer (score 1):

Are you using interceptors in your Angular application? They might be sending `OPTIONS` requests, which could lead to HTTP status 0 issues. To address this, first, ensure your PHP script handles `OPTIONS` requests:

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    http_response_code(200);
    exit;
}
```

Additionally, don't forget to include `OPTIONS` in the allowed methods in your CORS settings:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
```

This modification in your server code ensures proper handling of `OPTIONS` requests and CORS compliance, potentially resolving the status 0 issue.

Comment: I have coded this header header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

Answer (score 0):

No CORS, header was good. But I found that I can't send an `OBJECT` with `httpClient.post`.

All is good when I cast Object to JSON before:

```
addMessage(message: Message) {
  let messageJSON=JSON.stringify(message)
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'insert_message.php', messageJSON, {responseType: 'text'})
```

Comment: after some test I have found that httpClient.post is perfect to add a param Object to my php backend and return JSON of Get ? strange it works...

Comment: Now all is good! It was a CORS problem with localhost:4200. after build and send it 'live' it's OK.

Comment: addMessage(message: Message) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      observe: 'response' as const,
      responseType: 'text' as const,
    };

    return this.http.post(
      this.baseUrl + 'insert_message.php',
      message,
      httpOptions
    );
  }